# Preg_Replace 4th occurance of slash with hash fail

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unknown modifier in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493489/unknown-modifier-in-regular-expression)

Hey guys I'm getting an Unknown Modifier warning (fail) when trying to 
replace the fourth slash in a sequence with a hashmark using preg_replace,
hoping you can help.

```
$value['path'] = preg_replace("/((.*?)(/)){4}/e", '(preg_replace("//$/", "", "\0"))#', $value['path']);
```

Error:

```
Warning: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Unknown modifier ')'
```

Comment: You should `s/\//\\\//g;` Or, actually, just use another delimiter - `#`, for example, - instead of `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `/` as a delimiter, you need to escape all `/` in the middle of the regex.

Personally I like to use `()` as delimiters, because it doesn't require any escaping and it reminds me that the first match (index 0) is the entire pattern.

Side-note: Do NOT use the `e` modifier. Use [`preg_match_callback`](http://php.net/preg-match-callback) instead.

Also, you can replace the 4th instance of a slash by doing something like this:

```
$parts = explode("/",$value['path'],5);
$last = array_pop($parts);
$value['path'] = implode("/",$parts)."#".$last;
```

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example?